# visualforce page shows uknown method error

Tags: salesforce, crm, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have 2 wrapper class as below

```
public class Wr_Studennt{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public decimal salary{get;set;}
    public decimal exp{get;set;}
    public string technology{get;set;}
    
}

public class Wr_Address {
    public String city{get;set;}
    public string place{get;set;}
    public string pincode{get;set;}
    public String state{get;set;}
}
```

I have apex class as below

```
public class wr_Student_Address {
    public Wr_Studennt st{set;get;}
     public wr_student_Address()
    {
        st=new Wr_Studennt();
        
           }
    public void setstudent(string name,decimal salary,decimal exp,string technology)
    {
        st.name=name;
        st.salary=salary;
        st.exp=exp;
        st.technology=technology;
        
    }
    
    
}
```

My VF page isas below

```
<apex:page controller="wr_Student_Address">
    <apex:form>
   <apex:pageblock title="Student Details">
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        <apex:outputLabel value="Name: "/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!name}" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Salary: "/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!salary}" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Exp: "/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!exp}" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Technology: "/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!technology}" />
       
          <apex:commandButton value="setstudent" action="{! setstudent}" />
        
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>


</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

It shows

> Unknown property 'wr_Student_Address.name' error in line 0.

Please help me solving this issue.
visualforce page shows

> unknown method error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page controller `wr_Student_Address` has only 1 property: `st`. There's no field called `name` directly in this class.

Try with merge field `{!st.name}`

Comment: That is resolved but now it shows Unknown method 'wr_Student_Address.setstudent

Comment: Is this real code, is the variable name `st` or `student`? Because if you have `public Wr_Studennt student{set;get;}` the setter takes the form of setVariableName so it becomes setStudent. And it's "stronger" than you defining extra function explicily named `setstudent`. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/9167/799 (it's about "getter" not being called but same idea). Maybe call the function something else like `save` to be safe? And reference the new name in VF